# Build disappears after uploading to iTunesConnect

Tags: ios, xamarin, build, xamarin.ios, app-store-connect

I am trying to upload build from Xamarin studio with application loader.
I have set all the Privacy usage description as i was missed to key before (Which were suggested by Apple)
and the keys are following with description :-

1) Location When In Use Usage Description :- Need to access Location for posting latitude longitude for event.

2) Privacy - Camera Usage Description :- This app needs access to the camera to take photos

3) Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description :- This app needs access to photos

4) Privacy - Contacts Usage Description :- For getting list of user contacts

5) Privacy - Calendar Usage Description :- use to set date of event

6) NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription :- [App Name] would like to make data available to nearby bluetooth devices even when you're not using the app.

7)Privacy - Location Usage Description :- Need to access Location for posting latitude longitude for event

Build got validate and uploaded to iTunes successfully.
But for 15-20 minutes i can see only "Processing" in Activity tab in iTunes and when i reload page , its disappear.

My BitCode is Also Disable.

Comment: Please check out the email in which you receive status from apple....hope it will show any error so you can debug....

Comment: It will appear again after some time. If it's not - contact Apple support.

Comment: @GouravJoshi i have already got mail for contacts and calendar usage description and i have added it but still facing issue.

Comment: This aways happens to me if while uploading, I minimise the Application Loader and take some other window or if the display turns off while it is uploading. It gets stuck at processing. Now I don't take any other windows while uploading, and it uploads just fine.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Please Select Requires Full Screen Before giving build. It Will solve your issue.

Comment: yes i have did the same but its not the thing which does not let me upload build..

Comment: Have you recieved any  mail From apple

Comment: In Mail Apple gives specific reason why your build is disappeared.

Comment: i have already got mail for contacts and calendar usage description and i have added it but still facing issue.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by just replacing NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription to Privacy - Bluetooth Peripheral Usage Description and apple sent me mail for "The app's Info.plist must contain an NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription key with a string value"